# ¿Cómo convertir a XML en C# empleando un objeto que contiene un arreglo?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xml, object

Deseo hacer un archivo xml con datos que recibo en mi controlador. Los datos están almacenados en objetos, y no hay problema con ello. Por ejemplo, el objetoUno.campo almacena un dato string y éste es bien convertido a xml. El problema inicia cuando quiero hacer lo mismo con el objetoDos.campo2 que contiene un array (vector={} el cual tiene 'n' datos) de strings. Con este segundo objeto, en vez de mostrarse datos, me aparece:

```
<objetoDos campo2="System.COllections.Generic.List'1[System.String]">
```

Este es un fragmento de mi código:
*clase del objetoUno con el que no hay problema

```
 public class objetoUno 
    {
    public string campo {get:set}
    }
    XElement campo = XElement.Parse(Globals.SerializeTool.Serialize<objetoUno>(objetoUno));

//objetoDos (contiene el array)
public class objetoDos 
{
public List<string> campo2{ get; set; }
}

XElement campo2 = XElement.Parse(Globals.SerializeTool.Serialize<objetoDos>(objetoDos));
```

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Por qué no usas la serializacion a Xml directa que provee .NET Framework? La serializacion a XML tiene unas cuantas particularidades como que solo seserializan las propiedades publicas, hace falta un contructor vacío en la clase a serializar, etc Te recomiendo eches un vistazo a este tema en [Introducing Xml Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.110).aspx)
Te paso un ejemplo completo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public class Basket
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // instanciamos un objeto Basket con varios Items
            Basket basket = new Basket()
            {
                Name ="Basket1",
                Items = new List<Item>() 
                { 
                    new Item() { Name = "Item1" },
                    new Item() { Name = "Item2" },
                    new Item() { Name = "Item3" }
                }
            };

            // instanciamos el serializador XML
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Basket));

            using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, basket);
                Console.WriteLine(textWriter.ToString());

            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

La salida de este programa de consola sería

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Basket xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>Basket1</Name>
  <Items>
    <Item>
      <Name>Item1</Name>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>Item2</Name>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <Name>Item3</Name>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</Basket>
```

Comment: Hola @Mariano. He agregado un ejemplo. Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Se necesita una concatenación previa de los elementos de la lista, ya que el método Parse acepta por parámetro un string que contiene el XML.

Por ejemplo:

```
public class ObjetoPrueba
{        
    public List<string> listaCadenas { get; set; }

    public ObjetoPrueba()
    {
        listaCadenas = new List<string>();
    }
}

string listaCadenas = "";
ObjetoPrueba objetoPrueba = new ObjetoPrueba();
objetoPrueba.listaCadenas.Add("<Raiz>");
objetoPrueba.listaCadenas.Add("<Hijo>");
objetoPrueba.listaCadenas.Add("Hijo1");
objetoPrueba.listaCadenas.Add("</Hijo>");
objetoPrueba.listaCadenas.Add("<Hijo>");
objetoPrueba.listaCadenas.Add("Hijo2");
objetoPrueba.listaCadenas.Add("</Hijo>");
objetoPrueba.listaCadenas.Add("</Raiz>");

foreach (string cadena in objetoPrueba.listaCadenas)
{
    listaCadenas = listaCadenas + cadena;
}

XElement campo2 = XElement.Parse(listaCadenas);
```